# What are some methods / guidelines / tutorials for doing user interviews before developing a piece of software?

Tags: interview

The stuff behind the scenes, such as the database, is simple and flexible, so I don't have to consider that. So this is all about what the users need, and that means what he needs in the GUI (it's a web application).

I know this is a very wide question. I could ask it much more specifically, but I think there has to be people out there, used to attack such problems, that have very general guidelines.

It could be great, if you have some resources for learning more, whatever your answer is.

Comment: Short answer: Please have a read of Indi Young's book Mental Models http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/mental-models/

Comment: It feels to me that if you are still trying to figure out what he needs in the UI (and if this is at the level I think you mean) then this means you might need to consider working with user stories. After you've scoped the problem with your user stories you can then start thinking of how you can fulfill those stories with your UI. After that you can start prototyping and doing some usability testing with your client.

Answer (score 0):

The job of a UX/UI expert is to figure out what the user needs in the UI. You can ask direct questions such as "What feature would you like to see on the home screen" and they'll look at you with a blank stare. Some of them will try and be helpful and give you answers, but you'll get half-truths. Most won't know what they need. They just know they need something simple and intuitive.

The best thing to do is dig down to the core and discover their true issues. What is failing with their current solution. Why is it inadequate. You'll get a bunch of useful info on what doesn't work. Your job is to take the info and for a hypothesis. Then test it (implement it in the software). Measure (A/B testing etc..) and refine.